# Show that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ there is $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\arcsin(\sin(x))=(-1)^kx+k\pi$. and $\arccos(\cos(x))=(-1)^kx+k\pi.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Show that for all $x\in\mathbb R$ there is $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$\arcsin(\sin(x))=(-1)^kx+k\pi$$.

and

$$\arccos(\cos(x))=(-1)^kx+k\pi.$$

Induction is not valid right, domain it´s not $\mathbb N$.

Comment: What's your definition of $\sin$ and $\arcsin$?

Comment: I take a sine of an angle and match sin(x), where x is a number (an arc length)
I don't usually use the definition of sine with Riennam

Comment: CPMP, if you add more context to your question, I will answer it. Please, click [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and read.